# Canont get a ImageView to center within a horizontal conatiner

Tags: android

I hav e a ImageView inside a horizontal container and have the gravity set to center.  It is drawn right justified.  The image above it, not in a horizontal canter is centered.

Am I doing something wrong, or objects inside a horizontal container cannot be centered???
code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="In case of Emergency: Break Glass"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />    


   <ImageView           
            android:id="@+id/butMenu"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"

        />    

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <ImageView            
            android:id="@+id/butMenu"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"

        />       

    </LinearLayout> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not use a single relative layout?

Comment: that's because your horizontal linearlayout doesn't care about horizontal gravity. remove it, or make it wrap content and centered itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add  `android:gravity="center"`in your parent container.

Below is your updated layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="In case of Emergency: Break Glass"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff7f1d2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/butMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  `ImagView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2" >

      <ImageView            
            android:id="@+id/butMenu"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"

        />       

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upps, didn't know that so far: You really cannot center a view horizontally in a horizontal orientated LinearLayout!

**Thinking about it**, it might not make many sense to center a view horizontally in a horizontal LinearLayout. Or center vertically in a vertical LinearLayout. Android must assume during the layout process, that more views are yet to come in the defined orientation.

Distributing views in the LinearLayout, therefore `android:layout_weight` was introduced.

**But you can** simply set the width of the ImageView to the width of the parent and center the image inside the view horizontally.

```
      <ImageView            
        android:id="@+id/butMenu2"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```